# Problem passing php dynamic variable to jquery in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I made a php script that loads a random bird picture from my servers picture library, then extracts the name of the species of the bird using exifdata and finally storing the name in a php variable called $art.

The php script is executed via the "xyz php snippet"-plugin in wordpress on a web-page and works as intended. I have tried passing the variable $art using wp_add_inline_script but the browser console always returns null.

the php script:

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
$dir_path = "wp-content/uploads/Arter";
$files = scandir($dir_path);
$count = count($files);
$index = rand(2, ($count-1));
$dir_pathsub = $files[$index];
$files = scandir($dir_path. '/' .$dir_pathsub);
$count = count($files);
$index = rand(2, ($count-1));
$filename = $files[$index];
echo '<a href="/'.$dir_path."/" .$dir_pathsub. '/' .$filename.'" target="_blank">
    <img src="/'.$dir_path."/" .$dir_pathsub. '/' .$filename.'" alt="'.$filename.'">
</a>';
$size = getimagesize ( $dir_path. '/' .$dir_pathsub. '/' .$filename, $info);       
        $iptc = iptcparse($info["APP13"]);        
$art = $iptc["2#025"][0];    
echo $art;
?>
```

The code in my themes functions.php:

```
wp_register_script(
'quiz',
 get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/quiz.js',
 array( 'jquery' ),
 1.0,
 true
  );

wp_enqueue_script( 'quiz' );
$dataToBePassed = array(
'rigtigt' => $art,
'forkert' => 'TEST'
);

wp_add_inline_script( 'quiz', 'const quizParams = ' . json_encode( $dataToBePassed ), 'after' );
```

The quiz script looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("button").click(function(){
  console.log(quizParams.rigtigt);
  console.log(quizParams.forkert);
  });
});
```

The wordpress-page:

```
[xyz-ips snippet="jQuerytest"] //the php script explained above
```

and then a block with custom html:

<button>Click for answer</button>

When pressing the button on my page the console returns null and 'TEST'

How do I pass the variable $art?

Edited 18/3 to include the php script.

Comment: Where is `$art` defined? That seems like the only question here.

Comment: $art is defined in the php scipt that runs via the xyz snippet -plugin.

Comment: And have you checked its value in PHP? Maybe it actually _is_ null.

Comment: I can echo the $art variable within the script and it displays fine on my page: https://futo.dk/test-page-for-quiz/ - but not "outside" the script - probably due to me missing some basic understanding on how variables are accessed?

Comment: Added the php script for clarification.